# Eclipse and git - every time I switch branches my JRE system library gets reset

Tags: eclipse, git

On different dev machines (some Win, some Mac) my JREs are in different places. On my Mac, every time I fetch or switch branches I seem to have to reset my JRE paths to System default from an explicit JDK version. Where is this information stored and how do I keep this out of git, or deal with it in a better fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information, when specified on a project level, is stored in the .classpath file.  You should either tell git to ignore that file (it's quite common to ignore "dot resource" files) or you should change the classpath file to use the default JVM.

Do the latter by selecting the project and selecting "Build Path -> Configure Build Path" in the context menu. Go to the Libraries tab, select the JVM listed and click "remove".  Next click on "Add Library..." and choose "JRE System Library".  After clicking "Next" choose the default JVM and click "OK".

One more related comment.  If you were to use maven, a lot of these build configuration issues would go away.  Of course, there's a bit of a learning curve cost to that, too.